# Copy files with parent folder to a new directory

Tags: awk, find, cp, xargs, cut

I want to copy some files and include their parent directory in the process.

The current structure is similar to:

```
/Module1/A/downloads/m13312/file.pdf
/Module1/A/downloads/m17312/file.pdf
/Module1/B/downloads/m18312/file.pdf
/Module2/A/downloads/m19312/file.pdf
```

I want to grab the final two sections of the path so that I end up with:

```
/mydir/m13312/file.pdf
/mydir/m17312/file.pdf
/mydir/m18312/file.pdf
/mydir/m19312/file.pdf
```

I've tried to use `cut` and `awk` to get the right results but I just cannot seem to get the path to return properly. Here's an example to just echo what I need (I haven't got to the copying part yet):

```
find . -type 'f' -path '*downloads*' -print0 | xargs -0 -I {} echo `cut -d/ -f4-5 <<<{}`
```

This just prints out the whole path so I know that I can't use this yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your `pax` supports the `-0` option:

```
find . -type 'f' -path '*downloads*' -print0 |
  pax -rw0s'|.*downloads/||' /mydir
```

Comment: Never even heard of pax before - but this did what I wanted in a single command.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
for file in /Module*/*/downloads/m13312/file.pdf
do
    file_directory="/mydir/$(basename "$(dirname "$file")")"
    mkdir -p "$file_directory"
    cp "$file" "$file_directory"
done
```